# Excel formula to look at multiple columns for determination

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to make a determination and output a string based on multiple columns of data and tiers/thresholds.

Basically, clients need to fit into 1 category based on activity. I've tried a bevy of if's and or's and and's and just can't seem to get it right.

i.e. with the below, Client A would be designated in Tier 2, because they have 3 users.

Client E would fit into Tier 1 becuase they had 0 item views, less than 300 queries, and 2 users with activity.

[image]

Is there an easy excel tool that could build this complex if statemtent, or a snip of vb code that could accomplish this better? Having no luck with the attempt below (places clients in to wrong tiers):

```
=IF((AND(H2<3,F2<=300)),"Tier 1",IF((AND(H2<5,H2>2,F2>300,F2<1000)),"Tier 2","Tier 3"))
```

Comment: How do you decide to use one or the other criteria? Which ever gets the highest price?

Comment: Without a proper definition of the rules you want to apply,  any answer to this can only be a guess

Comment: wound up using:
=IF(AND(H2<=2,F2<=300,G2<=0),"Tier 1",IF(AND(H2<=4,F2<=1000,G2<=500),"Tier 2","Tier 3"))

Answer (score 1):

This formula use OR and returns the highest value if any of the thresholds are crossed:

```
=MAX(AGGREGATE(15,7,$B$16:$D$16/(B5<=$B$14:$D$14),1),AGGREGATE(15,7,$B$16:$D$16/(C5<=$B$15:$D$15),1),AGGREGATE(15,7,$B$16:$D$16/(D5<=$B$13:$D$13),1))
```

Still do not know what you want with D

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create readable functions with, CONCATENATE, SWITCH, CHOOSE, or IFS functions.

Basic example:

```
=CHOOSE(IF(D2<=2,1,0)+IF(D2<=4,1,0)+IF(D2<=10,1,0),"TIER 1","TIER 2","TIER 3")
```

Useful link:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/06/06/excel-nested-if-statement/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($B$11:$D$11,,MATCH(1,(B2<=$B$13:$D$13)*(C2<=$B$14:$D$14)*(D2<=$B$12:$D$12),0))
```

It's just not clear where `Client D` should be

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]